# Instance variable released when using dispatch_async?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I initialize an object of class myClass from a controller, then executes 3 methods on this object inside 3 different `dispatch_async` functions.
Here is myClass:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
  @property (retain) NSString* aString;

  -(void)method1;
  -(void)method2;
  -(void)method3;

@end

@implementation myClass
@synthetize aString;

-(void)method1 {

  aString = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_file"];
  [someData writeToFile:aString];

  // ...
}

-(void)method2 {

  // ...
}

-(void)method3 {

 aFunction([aString UTF8String]);
}

@end
```

and the controller

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{

   myClass* myObject = [[myClass alloc] init];
}

-(void)meth1 {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [myObject method1];
   });
}

-(void)meth2 {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [myObject method2];
   });
}

-(void)meth3 {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [myObject method3];
   });
}
```

`meth1`, `meth2` and `meth3` are executed when 3 specific notifications are received, but they are always executed once in the same order.

When `meth3` is executed, I get `[NSPathStore2 UTF8String]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x107eb36a0`. When enabling NSZombie, Instruments tells me that `aString` was released by libdispatch.dylib . I can circumvent this issue by `copy`'ing `aString` in `method1` and releasing it at the end of `method3`. Nonetheless I don't think that's the right way to do, and it seems weird that instances variables are deallocated by libdispatch.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That isn't your real code;  `myObject` is defined as a local and there are no calls to any methods that would demonstrate teh problem.

Comment: the code you posted here shouldnt even compile. give us your real stuff if you want help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aString` as a property - `self.aString` (note that `self.myString = anotherString;`  is just a `[self setMyString:anotherString]`), so it will retain this string for you (as you mentioned in a property declaration) like this:

```
- (void)setMyString:(NSString *)newString {
    [newString retain];
    [_myString release];
    // Make the new assignment.
    _myString = newString;
}
```

Every property backed up with an iVar, so using iVar directly (without dot syntax) will not call setter (and also will not retain new value for you).

Take a look at Apple Docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW4)

**Edit**:

`stringByAppendingPathComponent:` is a factory method, so it will return you an autoreleased string.

Comment: thanks ! could you explain the difference between `self.aString` and `aString` ? Is `aString` considered as a local variable when using a block ?

Comment: take a look at my edits above

Answer (score -1):

You are modifying aString within a block so it's value won't be retained. You need to use __block to have the value retained once the block is finished executing.